# reindexing the content in Jive 4.5.5.0

Tags: java

I have following space structure.

```
  Test
       help
       general
   Main           
       contact
```

I want to move general  to Main space.

```
   Test
       help
   Main
       general
       contact
```

I am using Jive 4.5.5.0. From Admin console we have option to moving a sub space to another space. I am not sure about the re-indexing of the content. I think this is manual process.

Can some help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I stumbled across it so I'll answer anyway. You should not have to re-index the content when moving it.  If, however, you do need to rebuild the search index, you can do so in the admin console under System > Settings > Search.  But re-indexing takes up a lot of resources in 4.5, so don't do it during peak usage hours.